# How to have a loop within a form and have the values sent when form is submitted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

```
  <%= form_for(@foo) do |f| %>
    <% @bar.each do |b| %>
      <%= b.jar %>
    <% end %>
  <% end %>
```

How to send the values of b.jar when form is submitted?

Comment: How do you want them sent? As an array of numbers? Individual fields? Please provide more details.

Answer (score 2):

You just need to send them as actual form fields then:

```
<%= form_for(@foo) do |f| %>
  <% @bar.each do |b| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag b.name, b.jar %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

You do it for any other type of field too:

```
<%= text_field_tag b.name, b.jar %>
```

Note that this assume each @bar had a name attribute. If it doesn't, you need to make sure you use a way to give it a unique name, such as passing the key in your loop and using the number:

```
<%= form_for(@foo) do |f| %>
  <% @bar.each_with_index do |k, b| %>
    <%= hidden_field_tag "name#{k}", b.jar %>
  <% end %>
<% end %>
```

Comment: I fixed it. The value still doesn't pass.

Comment: Any desire to help us out with what exactly didn't work?

Answer (score 0):

I got the answer to this.    instead of  <%= hidden_field_tag b.name, b.jar %> I had to use     <%= f.hidden_field b.name%>. It worked for me.